# chromium with two tabs in kiosk mode

Tags: chromium, kiosk

I want to create a kiosk that always has two tabs open.

I've found plenty of articles that show how to open chromium on boot in kiosk with one webpage. But is there any way to create a kiosk mode with two tabs and to make sure those tabs can't be closed?

Comment: Do you control the web pages?

Comment: I don't control the pages, they are payroll websites from outside vendors that we want employees to be able to access via these PC's but nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, Kiosk mode only allows for one tab and no access to the browser chrome.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. The easiest way around this would probably be to create your own webpage that has HTML tabs and embeds your vendor pages in iframes.
2. Create a browser plugin (or utilize something like greasemonkey) that inserts the solution or something that accomplishes the same goal as #1.
3. Add a button(s) to the kiosk that will run a script to change the page available to the user through the kiosk.
4. Run multiple kiosks.